# BotBuilder-Api C# Dialogs return in previous "ResumeAfter" function

Tags: c#, botframework

Bot Builder C#, version :  3.15.2 
Net Framework : 4.7

Azure Web Application /
Channel Bot Registration

I have a problem with use of dialogs when have multiple :
context.Call(new MyNewDialog(Object1 Param1, Object2 Param2), this.MyNewDialogResumeAfter);

Sometimes the dialog return in previous "ResumeAfter" function and i doesn't say why, they haven't exception. It can appear since any dialog.

It appear on multiple channel like : teams, directLine or WebChat i doesn't try the other.

I'm looking to reproduce this on a small code and post this on GitHub.

Note: Today i have up the BotBuilder version to 3.15.3 and this doesn't appear.

Comment: "I'm looking to reproduce this on a small code and post this on GitHub." great, because without this, we can't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Bot Framework.  There is/was a lengthy discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4477).  The bug was introduced around version 3.14 and the current version (at the time of posting this) 3.15.3 addresses this.

The issue has to do with the data structure we were using for caching state data and its behavior.  We are no longer using a MemoryCache for this and have reverted back to using a Dictionary.  You can find the changes [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/commit/57562abb6012bd1d98d04c09d9039d7d157e65d8) if you are interested

Comment: Thx Jasson, for your explain. I'm going to read the discussion.